# Is $PATH environment variable of a desktop environment different from that in a shell?

Tags: desktop, qt, qtcreator

I am trying to find the `.desktop` file for qtcreator, so I write this:

```
$ for p in ${XDG_DATA_DIRS//:/ }; do
    grep -rni 'qtcreator' $p;
done
```

And here is the most relevant lines:

```
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu:ubuntusdk.desktop:2:X-AppInstall-Package=qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu:ubuntusdk.desktop:6:Exec=qtcreator %F
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu:ubuntusdk.desktop:7:Icon=ubuntu-qtcreator
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/qtcreator:qtcreator.desktop:2:X-AppInstall-Package=qtcreator
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/qtcreator:qtcreator.desktop:6:Exec=qtcreator %F
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/qtcreator:qtcreator.desktop:7:Icon=QtProject-qtcreator
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/qhimdtransfer:qhimdtransfer.desktop:12:#Icon=qtcreator_logo_32
```

I think the `qtcreator:qtcreator.desktop` is the desktop entry for QtCreator, so I open it and find out:

```
[Desktop Entry]
X-AppInstall-Package=qtcreator
X-AppInstall-Popcon=292
X-AppInstall-Section=universe

Exec=qtcreator %F
Icon=QtProject-qtcreator
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Qt Creator
GenericName=Integrated Development Environment
MimeType=text/x-c++src;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-xsrc;application/x-designer;application/vnd.nokia.qt.qmakeprofile;application/vnd.nokia.xml.qt.resource;
Categories=Qt;Development;IDE;
InitialPreference=9

X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=app-install-data
```

**qtcreator is not in the variable $PATH of the shell**. But I can still launch QtCreator in gnome unity.

From the [freedesktop-exec-variables](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables) I noticed

> If no full path is provided the executable is looked up in the $PATH environment variable used by the desktop environment.

#### Question

Is $PATH environment variable of a desktop environment different from that is a shell?

If so, where is the config file containing the $PATH variable for desktop environment?

I install a newer version of QtCreator then launch QtCreator in desktop and find out it references to the newer version without changing the `qtcreator:qtcreator.desktop` file. I think there is something to with the path of qt?

Desktop environment: gnome

OS: ubuntu16.04

**Edit**

The actual problem I encountered was not about $PATH(see my answer blow). Gilles' answer is actually the answer to `Is $PATH environment variable of a desktop environment different from that in a shell?' so I accepted it in case that someone has the same doubt as me.

Comment: @steeldriver thanks, problem solved. Found the wrong desktop entry file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is $PATH environment variable of a desktop environment different from that is a shell?

It may be.

The environment of a program does not come from a file, unless the program goes out of its way to read environment variables from a file. Each process inherits the environment of its parent. Reading environment variables from a file is part of the job of the program you run upon login (a shell when logging in in text mode, a session manager or the program that acts as such when logging in in a graphical environment). So normally, if you use your desktop environment and open a shell in a terminal, that shell would have the same environment as the desktop environment.

However, in practice, this may not be the case, because there's a ton of advice on the web telling people to put environment variable definitions in `.bashrc`. [That's a bad idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/is-there-a-bashrc-equivalent-file-read-by-all-shells/3085#3085) because it means that these environment variables are not available to programs started directly from the GUI, rather than started from a terminal. But if you've done that, you may find that you have different environment variables in a terminal compared to what you have in the desktop environment and in programs not launched from a terminal.

Putting environment variable definitions in `~/.profile` works on most systems. I think it works for Gnome on Ubuntu 16.04 as long as you don't activate Wayland (which breaks a lot of things, including login settings, and doesn't always offer a way to recover).

In any case, the usual symptoms of putting environment variables in the wrong place is that environment variables are present in a terminal, but missing in the desktop environment. For it to be the other way round, you would have to have something unusual in your shell startup files.

> qtcreator is not in the variable $PATH of the shell.

I very much doubt it, if it's installed. Ubuntu ships `qtcreator` in `/usr/bin` which is where most programs are located.

But note that `$PATH` has nothing to do with the location of the `.desktop` file. `$PATH` is for application programs, not for `.desktop` files. If you're looking for the `.desktop` file for `qtcreator`, and you have the `qtcreator` package installed, you can just [search for the file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locate_(Unix)):

```
$ locate qtcreator.desktop
/usr/share/applications/qtcreator.desktop
```

`/usr/share/applications` is the standard location for `.desktop` files.

If you've installed your own version of QtCreator in addition to the one in Ubuntu, then you should ensure that `qtcreator` is in the command search path, i.e. `$PATH`. If you installed it system-wide, you should have it available as `/usr/local/bin/qtcreator`, which is on the command search path before `/usr/bin`, so you'll get your version in preference to the system one. If you installed it on your account, create a symbolic link from wherever the `qtcreator` executable is to `~/bin/qtcreator`, i.e. to the directory `bin` under your home directory (if this directory doesn't exist, create it). Ubuntu's default `.profile` adds `~/bin` to the front of `$PATH`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @Gilles. `qtcreator` is not in `/usr/bin` because I uninstalled the original one and install from source again but didn't add to the $PATH. Although the true problem is I found the wrong `.desktop` file, your answer suits the title so I am gonna accept this.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` is not the only search path for `*.desktop` file. So I found the wrong QtCreator desktop entry file.

See the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-0.6.html)

> There is a single base directory relative to which user-specific data files should be written. This directory is defined by the environment variable $XDG_DATA_HOME.
>
> $XDG_DATA_HOME defines the base directory relative to which user specific data files should be stored. If $XDG_DATA_HOME is either not set or empty, a default equal to $HOME/.local/share should be used.
>
> $XDG_DATA_DIRS defines the preference-ordered set of base directories to search for data files **in addition to the $XDG_DATA_HOME base directory**. The directories in $XDG_DATA_DIRS should be seperated with a colon ':'.

I found the true QtCreator desktop entry file `~/.local/share/application/DigiaQt-qtcreator-community.desktop`.

The Exec line is `Exec=/home/user/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator`, so the problem is not about `$PATH`.

I installed both the older and newer version of QtCreator from source. There is an `InstallationLog.txt` under Qt directory. The action of copying the desktop file to `~/.local/share` is documented there.