# Should bashrc commands support shell reloading?

Tags: bash, shell

Whenever one reloads the shell without opening a new terminal, with `exec $SHELL`, `bashrc` files get executed again.

The question is:

**Should commands intended to run at shell startup explicitly support this operation?**

Of course, shell functions don't survive shell process replacement, but envvars do.
As such, a usual side effect is stuff getting added into `PATH` multiple times.

**To stay objective, I'm primarily interested whether there are any official guidelines regarding this.**

Comment: I don't understand. The entire point of `.bashrc` is that it is read each time you start a new interactive shell. `exec bash` starts such a shell (although just `bash` is usually what you want). How else would it work?

Comment: @terdon What I mean is whether commands run from `bashrc` should detect if you are doing a shell reload and avoid doing things twice.

Comment: What is the difference? I mean, by definition, this file is executed whenever you start a new shell. You are starting a new shell, so why would they not be executed? Perhaps you have put things in `~/.bashrc` that belong in `~/.profile` instead? See [Is there a ".bashrc" equivalent file read by all shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3085) and the links therein.

Comment: The difference is things can break if they don't detect this. E.g. in the case of `PATH` manipulation, entries may now be in a wrong order.

Comment: Yes, which is one of the reasons why PATH has no business being set in `.bashrc`. Read the answer I linked to above, PATH settings belong in `.profile`. `.bashrc` should only have things you want to run on each new shell you open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.bashrc` file is designed to hold things you *want* executed each time a new interactive shell is started. This isn't the right place to set your `PATH` variable, for example, you should only have things that you need to run on each shell initialization.

This is why we have two "families" of configuration files for bash:

- `/etc/bashrc`, `~/.bashrc` are read each time a new  **interactive shell** that is **not a login shell** is started.
- `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile` (in that order) are sourced each time a new interactive login shell is started.

What this means in practice, for most systems, is that the `~/.profile` group of files are read once, when you log in and then the `~/.bashrc` files are read each time you open a new terminal or start a new interactive shell.

Therefore, if you see that things in your `~/.bashrc` are being executed and causing you problems each time you start a new shell, that means your system has been misconfigured and you're using `~/.bashrc` when you *should* be using `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`. In other words, yes, `.bashrc` is absolutely supposed to be executed every time you start a new interactive non-login shell.

Comment: _"that means you have misconfigured your system"_ -- not me but Ubuntu maintainers then. They run shells in Gnome-terminal as non-login shells by default.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev yes, that's normal. But the default Ubuntu `.bashrc` does not include any PATH commands. Precisely because "normal" shells (what you get when you open a new terminal in a GUI environment) are non-login shells. Debian (and by extension Ubuntu) have one odd thing in that the default `.profile` sources `.bashrc`, but not the other way around. So if your PATH is getting screwed up, it's because you or some other user of your machine added PATH settings to `.bashrc` where they don't belong.

Comment: But non-login shells don't run `~/.bash_profile`, and the X session "shell" doesn't run it at its startup, either. So in this mode, I never have a chance to run the code in `~/.bash_profile` -- which breaks your suggested way of action!

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev no, non login shells don't run it. Which is why you put environment variable definitions there: you run a login shell when you login and all your other shells inherit exported variables from it. Most GUI login managers also run `~/.profile`. `bash_profile` is specific to bash though and is only needed if you want bash to be different from other login shells

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function, found in /etc/profile

```bsh
pathmunge () {
    case ":${PATH}:" in
        *:"$1":*)
            ;;
        *)
            [ ! -d "$1" ] && return
            if [ "$2" = "after" ] ; then
                PATH=$PATH:$1
            else
                PATH=$1:$PATH
            fi
    esac
}
```

That detects if a directory is already in the PATH before adding it.

Use it in your ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile:

```bsh
path_munge /directory/to/add before
# or
path_munge /directory/to/add/also after
```

to prepend or append the wanted dir to PATH.

Note that /etc/profile unsets the function, so copy it to your own profile.